# How can I logout of a siteminer SSO session from the server when my web session expires

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, session-timeout, siteminder

Our web session is required to timeout in 2 hours, while the siteminder SSO session timeout is like 4 hours.  Is there anyway to send a request to siteminder from my webapp to logoff my SSO session timeout.  What I have tried is to capture all the siteminder parameters in my webapp session when a user logs in (basically anything that starts with SM_).  Then in the HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed() method, I send a request to our siteminder logoff.html url after adding all the siteminder headers from the session. Nothing seems to happen with this approach - the next time I access a web page, a new web session is created and siteminder does not think I have logged out.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent)
{
    Map<String, String> siteminderHeaders = (Map<String, String>)sessionEvent.getSession().getAttribute("SM_HEADERS");

    if (siteminderHeaders != null){
        RequestCallback requestCallback = new SiteminderLogoutRequestCallback(siteminderHeaders);

        restTemplate.execute("https://mysiteminderhost/siteminderagent/ssologout/Logout.html", HttpMethod.GET, requestCallback, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand this correctly, a user is logging into SiteMinder (thereby receiving a SMSESSION cookie) and then accessing your application which is protected by a SM Web Agent instance (since you can read the SM_HEADERS the WA sets) and you wish to log the user out when your application reaches its timeout (2hrs) while the SM timeout is 4hrs?

Since the SM session information is stored in the SMSESSION cookie, why not just have your code set the SMSESSION cookie value manually (set-cookie) to "LOGGEDOFF"? Or if you simply redirect the browser to the SM specific logout.fcc page SM will handle the rest IIRC.

Comment: I originally tried to wait after the session timeout until another request came in, intending to redirect to the SM logout page.  The problem is that if there is no session I won't know if the request is after a SSO login or just a regular request that happened after the session timed out.  I have know way to tell the difference between those scenarios because the SM headers are the same either way.  Unless there is a SM header that indicates this came after a login attempt.

Comment: Why is the session kept even if the SMSESSION cookie is deleted? can some one please clarify? Thanks